# Callback for adding row to table on button press in MS Access Form

Tags: forms, ms-access

I am creating a form in MS Access 16.0.
When clicking a button, the value from the text box ("dummy_text_box") should be added as a new entry to the table Dummy_Table. I have tried adding a callback to the button, but I do not know how to add the value to the table.

In SQL, the command should look something like "INSERT INTO Dummy_Table (Dummy_Column) VALUES (<value_of_dummy_text_box>)

Please see figure. Sorry for "show me the code plz" type of post, but despite extensive googling of the subject I have not found a code snippet for doing this simple operation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: _Bind_ the form to the table, and you don't need the button. Also, do find a guide or tutorial "Beginning with Microsoft Access" or similar.

Comment: Yes, why are you not using a bound form? Otherwise, one way to create record is VBA code like `CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Dummy_table(Dummy_Column) VALUES('" & Me.tbxDummy & "')"`. Has nothing to do with Expression Builder.

Comment: @June7 From my understanding *) the bound form is only for mapping a single table to a form. I simplified the problem I am trying to solve a bit, in fact I have several input fields (Combo box, text boxes, check boxes) that in turn relates to different tables.
I am guessing that I can solve this particular problem by creating a view that links to several tables.
*) https://www.iaccessworld.com/the-difference-of-bound-and-unbound-form/

Comment: When I try to create a form from a single table the type of control does not become a Combo box but a List Box. When I change the List Box to a Combo Box only the first value in the table is shown (also when the dropdown menu is expanded). 
Also, once I have selected Expression Builder as the event for a button, I am unable to change the callback function, so I have to delete it and start over again. I am yet to find a tutorial that helps me understand the most logical workflow when creating forms in MS Access. I guess I could create the GUI in Python instead but that would feel like a defeat

Comment: A form normally enters/edits data for a single table. Form/subform arrangements are used for multiple table data entry of related records. I have NEVER used Expression Builder in an event property (actually never use that builder at all). I have (rarely) set an event to a VBA custom function call but I manually build the function reference just by typing in the event property. I have no problem editing the VBA code of referenced function. A field would not automatically be set up as either a combobox or listbox on form unless it is designed as such in table.

Comment: Comboboxes and listboxes often pull lists from 'lookup' tables. Those tables should not be edited through the form those combo/list boxes are set up on. Binding forms to tables is really the simplest way to accomplish data entry in an Access db. It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish with bound form.

Comment: Ok, thank you for a very clarifying answer. I will have another go at this tomorrow.

Comment: Regarding what I want to accomplish: I have a set of tables, representing a list of products (software applications / inventions). I want to make a GUI where items from different tables (inventor, classification etc) can be combined to create a new product item. The GUI should not require knowledge about SQL query syntax, and it should limit to which tables new values can be added. 

(For instance, the classification table cannot be changed, whereas inventors can be added by the end-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use code builder (button name is Command0):

```
Option Compare Database
Private Sub Command0_Click()
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [Dummy_Table](Dummy_Column) VALUES ('" & TextBox.Value & "')"
End Sub
```